# Android BroadcastReceiver doesn't always work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have two BroadcastReceivers one for sms and one for network state. Both are working well but sometimes they don't trigger and require my to restart the phone in order trigger again. Here is my Manifest

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.beecell.aghanina.networkstate.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="905">
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.beecell.aghanina.sms.SMSReceiver"
        android:label="SMSReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="907">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And here is my sms receiver

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle == null)
            return;
        LogFile.write("seemless sms received" );
    }
}
```

What am I missing right there?

Also I found some posts on the internet that uses

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.GSM_SMS_RECEIVED"/>
```

What is the difference between `GSM_SMS_RECEIVED` and `SMS_RECEIVED` Should I provide both as actions ?